# Get list of all villages/towns in India

Tags: csv, census, address, india

This might have been asked before but I couldn't get a similar question.
I am working on an application which will have addresses in India populated using dropdowns till 4 levels.

```
State => District => Tahsil/Municpality(based on rural/urban) => Village/Ward(based on rural/urban).
```

Where can I get this data with full hierarchy? I checked few places but couldn't get all the data as a single file or in a few files. I got a list of villages [from here](https://data.gov.in/catalog/complete-villages-directory-indiastatedistrictsub-district-level-census-2011) but this will give out 35 files for 35 states and it doesn't have Urban wards.

Comment: I think this is covered in this question, especially either OSM or Geonames. https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/3291/1511

Answer (score 1):

Yo can get all the required data from official website [data.gov.in](https://data.gov.in/catalog/complete-villages-directory-indiastatedistrictsub-district-level-census-2011). The data seems to be divided into state level, so maybe you will have to download ~31 csvs'. They have csv, ods, etc. they also support api calls, yo can check this feature, which could save you from downloading separate files.

Comment: The OP says that these files do not contain urban wards...