# Looking for corpus of Geographic Data

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I was wondering if anyone has a lead on a corpus of geographic locations? City names and coordinate pairs would be ideal. I'm training a chatbot and I'd (ideally) like it to be able to pick up on locations in the chat and then display a map if requested. For example, if the words "I'm headed to Chicago" were typed, the chatbot could render a map of Chicago. Wishes and wants aside, if y'all do know of one or how I could make one, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: As a note, I've done something like this at http://london.weather.94y.info/ where you can replace `london` with any place name (use dots to separate commas, eg, http://chicago.il.us.weather.94y.info/, although just http://chicago.weather.94y.info/ works too). My code is https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/WEATHER/bc-weather-text.pl and https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/bc-cityfind.pl -- feel free to contact me directly for help (contact info in profile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably lists, so if you are looking for single regions or languages, then this answer may be a bit much, but...

You can download the entire planet from Open Street Maps (OSM) and then filter out the relevant tags (see this [answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/12430/1511)). In your case you would filter on [`place`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:place), see this example filter:

```
./osmfilter planet.osm --keep="place=city =town =village" > my_places.osm
```

Your geocoordinates will actually be a multi-polygon, but that's OK because you can either simplify to a geopoint (e.g. use the centroid), or show the entire polygon range in your map.

Instead of planet.osm you can also do this for illinois.osm, or whatever region you want.

Comment: In this particular case, I think OSM might be overkill and geonames.org might suffice.

Comment: @BarryCarter can you add an answer? I had looked at geonames.org but didn't find one dataset that fit

Comment: My thought was just to download all of geonames.org (it's not that big) and use the whole thing to find placenames. I don't think my pointer is answer-worthy though-- just a general thought.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the geonames answer that should have been accepted.

Download one of the cities files ([readme.txt](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/readme.txt))

> **cities1000.zip**           : all cities with a population > 1000 or seats of adm div (ca 150.000), see 'geoname' table for columns
>
> **cities5000.zip**           : all cities with a population > 5000 or PPLA (ca 50.000), see 'geoname' table for columns
>
> **cities15000.zip**          : all cities with a population > 15000 or capitals (ca 25.000), see 'geoname' table for columns

The city name, ascii name, alternative name (etc) and latitude,longitude are available - one per row. In the readme search for *'geoname' table* for the column list descriptions

**[Link to export files](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump)**