# SPARQL get all the data before it reaches timeout

Tags: wikidata, sparql

I am trying to get **all the city names** of **all countries** in the world using this below query. Whenever I execute this below query it returns this message `"Query timeout limit reached"`.

Is there any other way to get all the data before it reaches timeout limit?

```
SELECT ?country ?countryLabel ?city ?cityLabel
WHERE
{
  ?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515;
        wdt:P17 ?country .

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
ORDER BY ?country
```

Comment: Probably won’t matter, but try without the ORDER BY?

Comment: Also asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57635621/sparql-get-all-the-data-before-it-reaches-timeout

Comment: btw, for city names, check out this question: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/3291/1511 and also this answer about geonames data: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/13081/1511

Answer (score 2):

Based on my [comment](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/15641/sparql-get-all-the-data-before-it-reaches-timeout#comment18580_15641), take out the `ORDER BY`.

---

Why? It has probably to do with the query optimizer, but I don't have any real explanation. In general, with SQL that I'm more familiar, `ORDER BY` when unnecessary is the first thing to take out when improving query performance.

---

(Note that this question was cross-posted at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57635621/2327328), and there is a longer discussion there.)